# Nested cross-validation for regression over small dataset

Tags: python, time-series, regression, cross-validation

I'm trying to do nested cross-validation for regression model parameter selection and prediction evaluation. I'm using temporal data (series of count).

The problem is that I don't have a lot of data for training and test so I'm to follow this process:

1. Split the data into two folds (80% - 20%)
2. Use standard GridSearchCV for parameter selection over the first
   fold
3. Evaluate the model with the best parameter by TimeSeriesSplit
   cross-validation. Here, I will use the whole dataset but I will define a new TimeSplit function to work like this: only the second fold will be divided into N subfolds and for each iteration i, the model learns on the first fold dataset (80%) + i subfolds of the second fold and test on the next subfold.

Did I perform the nested cross-validation properly so that my evaluation results are unbiased?

One other question, is it required to use TimeSeriesSplit cross-validation when using regression model over time series data?

Any help is appreciated